# Delete Item inside an Array of an Array in React and Redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I have an item inside an array of an array and I want to target it and delete it.
My problem is how do I access it and delete that particular item without mutating it.

Codesandbox is here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-added-array-of-object-inside-another-aray-in-react-forked-v6rnt?file=/src/components/MediaCard/index.js)

```
case appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.productImages.filter((item) => item !== action.payload)
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an additional payload - `product`. So that we can find the target product in `state.products` array by `productCode`. Suppose `ProductCode` can Identity a product.

Only use `imageFileName` is unable to determine which product it belongs to.

```js
case appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      console.log(state);
      const nState = {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map((item) => {
          if (item.productCode !== action.payload.product.productCode)
            return item;
          return {
            ...item,
            productImages: item.productImages.filter(
              (v) => v.imageFileName !== action.payload.imageFileName
            )
          };
        })
      };
      console.log(nState);
      return nState;
```

`App.js`:

```js
// ...
const onDeleteImage = (imageFileName, product) => {
    dispatch(deleteImage({ imageFileName, product }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {(products || []).map((product, index) => (
        <ProductCard
          product={product}
          key={index}
          onDeleteImage={(imageFileName) =>
            onDeleteImage(imageFileName, product)
          }
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
// ...
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-added-array-of-object-inside-another-aray-in-react-forked-9p811?file=/src/App.js:476-889)

Comment: Thank you. shouldnt we use useCallback, memo  etc... to avoid rerendering?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the conceptual solution:

```js
case appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map(product => ({
      ...product,
      productImages: (product.productImages ?? [])
        .filter(({imageFileName}) => imageFileName !== action.payload),
    })),
  };
```

Caveat: if more than one product has an image with the same file name as the one you are deleting, it will be deleted from the other products as well. (This is currently a limitation of the information provided in your payload.) If that description is a bug for your program, then you'll need to also provide a product ID in the payload so that you only filter images for the matching product.

Comment: Let's just assume the imageFileName is unique. could you fork my codesandbox? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, this should solve it for you. I copied this code and pasted it into your sandbox, replacing the existing case statement, and it appears to work as expected.

Comment: shouldnt we use useCallback, memo  etc... to avoid rerendering?

Comment: Hooks like `useCallback` are only for components and other hooks; your reducer is not inside a component or a hook, so no.

Comment: Yes. but what I mean is on the function onDeleteImage

Comment: That's not related to this answer. You can if you want, but there is no real performance benefit gained by doing so. That would be a micro-optimization that you shouldn't need to worry about.

Comment: I think its better to check productCode first, then go check ImageFileName?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `productIndex` or `id` along with the `imageFileName` to correctly do the delete. Otherwise, all the products having the same `imageFileName` will be deleted.

Try this

```
 case appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: (state.products || []).map((item, itemIndex) => {
          if (itemIndex === action.payload.productIndex) {
            return {
              ...item,
              productImages: item.productImages.filter(
                (image) => image.imageFileName !== action.payload.imageFileName
              )
            };
          }
          return item;
        })
      };
```

In App.js file

```
  const onDeleteImage = (productIndex, imageFileName) => {
    dispatch(deleteImage(productIndex, imageFileName));
  };
```

in actions index.js file

```
export const deleteImage = (productIndex, imageFileName) => {
  return {
    type: appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      productIndex,
      imageFileName
    }
  };
};
```

In MediaCard.js file

```
 <Button
          type="button"
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => onDeleteImage(productIndex, data.imageFileName)}
        >
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-added-array-of-object-inside-another-aray-in-react-forked-xmghr?file=/src/reducers/productReducer.js

Comment: @Joseph, check this out!!

Comment: Thank you. shouldnt we use useCallback, memo etc... to avoid rerendering?